# Inserting into multiple tables simultanteously (HEIDISQL)

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

flatpack_apn

components_apn

flatpackcomponents_apn

```
CREATE TABLE `component_apn` (
`componentno` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`description` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`componentno`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;


CREATE TABLE `flatpackcomponents_apn` (
`flatpackid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`componentno` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`quantity` INT(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`componentno`, `flatpackid`),
INDEX `flatpackid` (`flatpackid`),
INDEX `componentno` (`componentno`),
CONSTRAINT `flatpackcomponents_apn_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`flatpackid`) REFERENCES `flatpack_apn` (`flatpackid`),
CONSTRAINT `flatpackcomponents_apn_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`componentno`) REFERENCES `component_apn` (`componentno`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;


CREATE TABLE `flatpack_apn` (
    `flatpackid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    `colour` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `flatpacktype` ENUM('Office','Kitchen','Bedroom','General') NOT NULL,
    `unitprice` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`flatpackid`)
)
COLLATE='hp8_english_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2123
;
```

I am asked to:

Populate the tables with sample data using suitable data values and choosing values which are not offensive.
Flatpack: at least 5 flatpacks with at least 2 having more than 3 components
Component: at least 10 components

I am a little uncertain as to how to this.

I thought that:

```
INSERT INTO flatpack_apn 
SELECT *FROM components_apn


INSERT INTO flatpack_apn

SELECT quantity FROM flatpackcomponents_apn;
```

Is it possible to run them simultanteously, or would I need to execute them as two seperate events? Is there any downside to simply running them as two seperate insert events? In truth, I am not entirely sure I am interpreting the question above correctly.

As a sidebar; and apologies if I am asking too much in one question, but, I figured that I would be required to create/insert new columns within the table before adding the rows/records. Would this be a correct assumption?

Comment: Obviously you cannot insert into the child table  (`flatpackcomponents_apn`) before you populate the parents, as this would violate referential integrity constraints you have.

Comment: What version are you running?  I have not heard of 'hp8_english_ci'.

Answer (score 0):

The overhead and complication of spinning off two threads to run the queries simultaneously are almost always more costly than doing them sequentially.

Copying an entire table over is *normally* a rare task.  As such, the performance is often not a big deal.  Are you doing this as part of the normal flow?  If so, let's look at it in more detail to see if there is a better way to achieve the ultimate goal.

Don't use `TINYTEXT`.  `VARCHAR(255)` (or some smaller number) is virtually equivalent, yet more efficient in some situations.

Redundancy:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`componentno`, `flatpackid`),
INDEX `componentno` (`componentno`),    -- DROP, since the PK handles it.
```